# orientdb like query with node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, orientdb

I am working on an application with `orientdb`, `NodeJS`, `Express` and `AngularJS`. I am new to these technologies. I am writing a select query at the NodeJs end that returns data from OrientDB which is then displayed in frontend using AngularJS. But I wish to return only a part of the data when I enter value in a search key text box on homepage. 
I am following this [link](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs/blob/master/README.md) for OrientDb queries and trying this:

```
var key = "trade"
db.query('select from table where value like "%:searchkey%"', {
params: {
searchkey : key
        }   
}).then(function (results) {
        stringresult = results;
        res.json({"value":stringresult});

});
```

But the above code doesn't return any result. I tried playing around with the query, removing quotes from the `searchkey` and so on but that doesn't help either. This query works perfectly fine in the OriendDb console like this:

```
select from table where value like "%trade%"
```

The error might be because of the single or double quotes that I have used or the params but I am not sure.I have looked everywhere for a solution to this problem but could not find one.

Comment: what happens if you use db.query('select from table where value like "%trade%"').then... ?

Comment: @wolf4ood That works fine. But i can't hardcode it, since the value is coming from front end. The issue is somewhere in the single/double quotes or the params syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe the problem is that you're not putting the wildcards in properly. They need to be added to the key, and not the query.

```
var key = "trade"
db.query('select from table where value like :searchkey', {
params: {
searchkey : "%" + key + "%"
        }   
}).then(function (results) {
        stringresult = results;
        res.json({"value":stringresult});

});
```